# pip python not installing modules on linux

Tags: python, linux, pip

I have been trying to install win32api module using **pip install win32api** but whenever I try to, it gives me an error message:

> *Downloading/unpacking win32api   Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/   Could not find any downloads that
>   satisfy the requirement win32api Cleaning up... No distributions at
>   all found for win32api Storing debug log for failure in
>   /root/.pip/pip.log*

My repositories are alright. Help me out here.

By the way, I'm using kali linux 2.0 32 bit version

Comment: There is no package named 'win32api'. You can go and check on https://pypi.python.org. Please check the name.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using Windows, you need to get this package from here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/

This library is not available in Pip since it's Windows specific (won't work on Linux or OS X).

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the repositories to `sources.list`

Type this to open the file:

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

And add these lines:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

Save and run:

```
apt --fix-broken install
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade 
apt-get install python3-pip
```

And type:

```
pip --version
```